# Is it possible to fetch a custom size twitter profile image and if so - how?

Tags: php, image, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making an app which has both FB and Twitter connect, With facebook it was very easy but twitter documentation itself is simply frustrating, Maybe someone has come across this?

I managed to fetch twitter profile image but it's small, I am completely aware of this:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

However, I was wondering if it's possible to get a custom size photo, Some people told me that they have seen it done though no clue on how to do it. If someone could point me to the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:
I see my question was not clear enough. I wanted to ask if it is possible to get a custom sized photo just as with facebook API.

Let me rephrase the question:
Is anyone aware of the twitter profile image size (the original one). From what I have checked myself it seems they are all 400x400px.

There's no problem of checking the dimensions but if lots of profile images end up being of a different size - then I would rather not have this functionality at all and let users add their own image in my app.

It might as well be that this "custom sized profile image" is a myth.

Comment: What do you mean 'retrieve a custom size photo'. It gives you the sizes you can retrieve, you can generate a new image from that photo, or resize it with html/css. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I simply need a bigger picture that's all.

Comment: So grab the `original` make a comparison on it's size, if you can maintain the aspect ratio, then do it, otherwise you'll suffer quality loss.

Comment: I can maintain the aspect ratio (original twitter profile image usually comes 400x400 and I need 200x200) for the profile images I have checked. Yet I am not sure that they always come in this size.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are available here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

By modifying the URL, you can retrieve other variant sizings such as "bigger", "mini", and "original".

Comment: I am sorry but I have put this link in the description precisely because it does not answer anything as I have explicitly stated in my question :) 

Twitter stores profile images in the size of 400x400 pixels. If I could get that - I could resize it through php myself. Yet I am not sure if all of them are stored in 400x400 that's why I asked if it is possible to get a custom sized one.

Comment: Ah, even in that I was wrong. Found pictures in 512x512, 500x500 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it would seem that there is no possibility of getting custom sized photos from Twitter. Moreover the sizes of the profile pictures on Twitter can vary, so if you fetch a photo in original size, it can range from tiny to big.

I realize that it was rather a stupid question since I could've just checked on Twitter by uploading different size photos myself.

Twitter "recommends" using a profile picture size of 400x400 px.

So in my case for example, since I need a 200x200 px, I will have to fetch the original, check if the size is big enough or bigger, resize it while maintaining the aspect ratio, or not use it at all if it's too small as @Ohgodwhy suggested.

Thanks to everyone who invested some time for the answer. I still think that this should be clearly documented in the Twitter API docs instead of just saying that you can get an "original size profile image".